# Django CBV ListView, accessing both paginated and unpaginated results

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-pagination

I built a list view using generic view class ListView with pagination and search functionality. Now I want to include in the same page a map with markers for all the results, without pagination.

Is there a way to reach both paginated and unpaginated results without having to do a duplicate query?

Comment: Well, you will have to do a duplicate query, because pagination is done by sending offset/limit to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by override the method  `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)`. It takes only a single query.

```
class MyListview(ListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['obj_list'] = list(kwargs['obj_list'])
        my_obj_list = kwargs['obj_list']
        context = super(MyListview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['my_obj_list'] = my_obj_list
        return context
```